Gitlab: Using $CI_RUNNER_ID in resource_group
We are using Gitlab 17.2 and have a stage "test" that takes up to 4 hours to complete.
We need to use resource_group in our gitlab-ci script because if multiple "test" stages run on the same runner, the stage will crash because the database is locked during the execution of the test.
Since the test stage has such a long duration, I wanted to use multiple runners, so that the test stage can run in parallel, but on DIFFERENT runners.
The current situation is that one "test"-stage blocks all other "test"-stages in the whole project, across all branches.
I tried to use resource_group: $CI_RUNNER_ID, but it seems like predefined CI/CD variables of Gitlab can't be used with resource_group, because it doesn't get expanded.
Storing the value of $CI_RUNNER_ID in a variable, setting it in the before_script stage and using the variable in resource_group didn't work either. It seems there is no way to use variables dynamically with resource_group.
Is there any other way how i can achieve my goal?
